# Permissions for all filtered users to all mailboxes - Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, outlook, automation, exchange-server

I am trying to automate permissions on an Exchange Server.

In our environment there is a need to share all mailboxes inbetween a group of users (all users except few filtered-out ones).

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -filter {Alias -notlike 'admin*' -And Alias -notlike 'user1*' -And Alias -notlike 'user2*' -And Alias -notlike 'user3*' -And Alias -notlike 'user4*' -And Alias -notlike 'user5*' -And Alias -notlike 'user6*' -And Alias -notlike 'user7*' -And Alias -notlike 'user8*'} | foreach-Object { Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Alias -User $_.Alias -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All}
```

Currently each Alias gets FullAccess to itself.. How can I achieve giving permissions to all filtered users?

Comment: As I see you are using `-Identity $_.Alias` and `-User $_.Alias` this is the same.
`-Identity is the mailbox that you want to give access`
`-User is the user that is getting access to that mailbox`
e.g.
`Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Steftheo" -User VidMan -AccessRights Fullaccess -InheritanceType all`

This will grand VidMan full access to steftheo's mailbox

you must put the users in the -User parameter.
Maybe a loop with all the users within the loop of the mailbox.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a code here.

```
$MailboxeAlias = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {Alias -notlike 'admin*' -And Alias -notlike 'user1*'}
ForEach ($Mailbox in $MailboxeAlias) 
    { 
        $GroupUsers = Get-ADGroupMember "Groupname" | select Samaccountname
            Foreach ($User in $GroupUsers) 
            {
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User.SamAccountName -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All}
            }
```

With that code you get all the mailboxes and for each mailbox then you query the users in a group you want to have access to that and for each user in that group you run the permission command.

I don't know if it works as it is or maybe you need to make some fixes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing into the right direction! 

`c $MailboxeAlias = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {Alias -notlike 'admin*' -And Alias -notlike 'user1*'} ForEach ($Mailbox in $MailboxeAlias) { $GroupUsers = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {Alias -notlike 'admin*' -And Alias -notlike 'user1*'} | select Alias Foreach ($User in $GroupUsers) { Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User.Alias -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All} `